# Postfix does not get external emails

Tags: email, postfix

I have a small vserver(ubuntu), on which i want to run mailman and therefore have to configure postfix.

I already configured postfix to send mail per relay over gmail (server->ext.). I also receive local emails (server->server), but i dont get emails from ext. (ext. -> server).

I have a domain routed to the vserver. But when i send an email from external (e.g. from gmail) to root@mydomain.com i don't get it into the inbox. But there is also no error return message i get to my gmail account.

What could be a possible problem? Do i have to configure email revieving from external somewhere?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What happens when you telnet to port 25 on your machine and manually enter a basic SMTP conversation?

Comment: When i manually use port 25 on localmachine it works and i receive the mail. But when i telnet to mydomain.com on port 25 i get 'Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused'

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help.

I found out that the inet_interfaces property in the main.cf file was set to
only allow local connections.

Now it works.